# How to handle scarce resource disputes in a procurement system

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, transactions, knex.js

In the code below, when you have a purchase order for a product with 1 unit and two users try to buy at the same time, both are able to buy. I'm using transactions in this process and I believed that the transaction idea would handle this case.

I'm using DB postgres and I've already tested using ISOLATION LEVEL for this transaction, but without success.

```
try {
        //I tried this, but doesn't work
        const trx = await knex.transaction({ isolationLevel: 'read uncommitted' });

        let order_total = 0;
        const products = [];

        const sales = [];

        for (const pBought of data.products) {
            let prod = await trx('tb_product')
                .select('tb_product.id', 'tb_product.title', 'tb_product.price', 'tb_product.price_total', 'tb_product.quantity', 'tb_product.id_salesman', 'tb_product.width', 'tb_product.height', 'tb_product_discount.value', 'tb_product_discount.is_deleted')
                .leftJoin('tb_product_discount', 'tb_product_discount.id', 'tb_product.id_discount')
                .where({ 'tb_product.id': pBought.id_product, 'tb_product.is_active': true, 'tb_product.is_deleted': false });

            prod = prod[0];

            if (!prod) throw new Error('Produto inexistente!');

            let salesman = await trx('tb_salesman')
                .select('*')
                .where({ 'id': prod.id_salesman, 'is_deleted': false });

            salesman = salesman[0];

            if (!salesman) throw new Error('Vendedor inexistente!');

            if (salesman.id !== prod.id_salesman)
                throw new Error('Vendedor inconsistente!');

            if (!prod || !salesman)
                throw new Error('Não foi possível recuperar as informações!');

            if (pBought.quantity <= 0)
                throw new Error(`Quantidade informada de ${prod.title} menor que 1!`);
            console.log(prod.quantity, pBought.quantity);
            if (prod.quantity < pBought.quantity)
                throw new Error(`Quantidade de ${prod.title} maior que a disponível!`);

            if (prod.price !== pBought.price)
                throw new Error(`Preço de produtos inválido, atualize a página!`);

            let aux;
            if (prod.value && !prod.is_deleted) {
                aux = (prod.price - prod.value) * prod.width * prod.height;
                order_total += roundToTwo(aux * pBought.quantity);
            } else {
                aux = prod.price_total;
                order_total += roundToTwo(aux * pBought.quantity);
            }

            sales.push({
                id_salesman: salesman.id,
                id_product: prod.id,
                product_title: prod.title,
                quantity: prod.quantity,
                unit_price: parseInt(aux.toFixed(0)),
                price: pBought.quantity * aux
            });

            products.push({ id_product: prod.id, price: aux, discount: prod.value, quantity: pBought.quantity, available_quantity: prod.quantity, tax: process.env.PERCENTAGE_TAX });
        }

        let order = await trx('tb_order').insert({ order_total, id_client: client.client.id_client, id_address: address.address.id, portions: data.portions, method: data.method }).returning('*');
        order = order[0];

        for (const prod of products) {
            if (prod.available_quantity - prod.quantity)
                await trx('tb_product').update('quantity', prod.available_quantity - prod.quantity)
                    .where({ 'id': prod.id_product });
            else
                await trx('tb_product').update({ 'quantity': 0, 'is_active': false })
                    .where({ 'id': prod.id_product });

            delete prod['available_quantity'];

            prod.id_order = order.id;
        }

        await trx('tb_order_product').insert(products);

        const wasPaid = await Payment.execute(sales, { portions: data.portions, method: data.method, card_hash: data.card_hash, document: data.document, name: data.name, total: parseInt((order_total * 100)).toFixed(0) }, client, address, order.id);
        if (!wasPaid.success) throw new Error(wasPaid.message);
        trx.commit();
        return { success: true, order };
    } catch (error) {
        Message.warning(error);
        return { success: false, message: error.message }
    }
```

I'm using Node.js and Knex.

I want know how can I handle this scenario for allow only one user take a product at once.
Using serializable for isolation level I get error, because even non-scarce products cannot be acquired simultaneously, because it locks the table and, if another user tries to buy, any product that is at the same instant, will receive an error.

Comment: Have you tried making your initial select "for update"?

Comment: "Using serializable for isolation level I get error, because even non-scarce products cannot be acquired simultaneously, because it locks the table"  It should not predicate lock the entire table, unless there is no usable index.

Comment: Hey, @jjanes thanks for your comment. Can you please explain what the idea behind making an initial upgrade selection is? I did not understand.

Regarding the second comment, when I tried to use serializable, with multiple requests that write on the table product, one pass normally but anothers receive an error like "multiple write simultaneously"

Comment: Hey @jjanes, I researched about the "for update", implemented and it's works! Thank you a lot for this, saved me some hair wire hahaha. If you want write a response final for this topic I will give you the correct answer! Again thank you!

Comment: Select for update is the easiest answer for locking selected row so that no one else can use it meanwhile. The code is also leaking transactions when error happens, which will eventually fill the pool and cripple the app completely.